# Java Swing using JList with an ArrayList<>

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlist

Basically, I've got a CD Library that holds instances of a CD ArrayList<>, I've then got a people ArrayList<> that can "borrow" CD's... from that CD's are added to an available, or unavailable list.

```
public CDStore(String storeNme) {
        storeName = storeNme;
        discsArray = new ArrayList<CD>();
        peopleArray = new ArrayList<Person>();
    }
```

By using a JList, I'm trying to make the elements of the list equal the instances of CD.

So... item1 in the list would be the CD at index 0, item 2 = index 1 and so on....

```
String[] entries = ??????????????????;
        JList listOfCD = new JList(entries);
        listOfCD.setVisibleRowCount(4);
        JScrollPane listPane = new JScrollPane(listOfCD);
        JTextField valueField = new JTextField("None", 7);
```

Thankyou.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the name of the CD displayed in the List?

Comment: Essentially, yeah... Just want the elements of discsArray to be the element entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CDStore` could implement the interface [`ListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html). Than you can use the `CDStore` as a model for your `JList`.

```
CDStore store = new CDStore("Store");
// add some CDs

JList listOfCD = new JList(store);
listOfCD.setVisibleRowCount(4);
JScrollPane listPane = new JScrollPane(listOfCD);
JTextField valueField = new JTextField("None", 7);
```

Here is example implementation of `CDStore implements ListModel`. Everytime the `discsArray` changes you should call the method `fireContentsChanged`.

```
public class CDStore implements ListModel {
    private String storeName;
    private List<CD> discsArray;
    private List<Person> peopleArray;

    public CDStore(String storeNme) {
        storeName = storeNme;
        discsArray = new ArrayList<CD>();
        peopleArray = new ArrayList<Person>();
    }

    //your methods

    //ListModel
    private List<ListDataListener> listener = new ArrayList<ListDataListener>();

    public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
        listener.add(l);
    }

    public void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
        listener.remove(l);
    }

    protected void fireContentsChanged() {
        for (ListDataListener l : listener) {
            l.contentsChanged(new ListDataEvent(this, ListDataEvent.CONTENTS_CHANGED, 0, discsArray.size()-1));
        }
    }

    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        return discsArray.get(index);
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return discsArray.size()
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Also consider extending `AbstractListModel` to leverage existing implementations of some methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a method to retrieve CD name, let's call it getCDName(),
you can try

```
String[] entries = new String[discsArray.length];
int index = 0;
for (CD cd: discsArray) {
     entries[index++] = cd.getCDName();
}
```

This should fill in your entries array.

Comment: Tried what you said, but we're calling discsArray from another class... but for whatever reason it wont allow me to use the discsArray and asks me to create the method, etc. is there anyway to get around this?